# How to encode the operands for a sub immediate 83 /5 opcode, like sub edx, 0x3a?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, opcode, machine-code

I'm having trouble looking at assembly instructions such as this in GAS syntax

```
subl $0x3a, %edx
```

and then being able to use the Intel manual to manually produce the matching machine code which happens to be

```
83EA3A
```

I realize i go in the intel manual to the subtract page and seeing that we are subtracting an immediate from a register which would start us off with opcode 83/5 ib according to the intel manual but im a little lost where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, since the immediate fits in a sign-extended imm8, `83 /5` is the best choice.  The register operand is encoded in the rm field of a ModRM byte, as documented in the "Instruction Operand Encoding" table for that instruction, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub

Answer (score 2):

The opcode (83<sub>16</sub>) is followed by the ModR/M byte.
/5 (or /101<sub>2</sub>) is the Reg/Opcode field of the byte.
The Mod (11<sub>2</sub>) and R/M (010<sub>2</sub>) fields specify the register (edx).
Hence: 11.101.010<sub>2</sub> = EA<sub>16</sub>.

See:

- 2.1 INSTRUCTION FORMAT FOR PROTECTED MODE, REAL-ADDRESS MODE, AND VIRTUAL-8086 MODE of volume 2 of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual
- In particular, Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte